# Java JTable filter data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, keylistener, rowfilter

I can not correctly apply the filter to the JTable.

```
private static TableRowSorter<SQLiteTableModel> sorter = null;
...
private void jTFSearchOtherKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          

    jTableOther.setRowSorter(sorter);
    String text3 = jTFSearchOther.getText();
    if (text3.length() == 0) {
        sorter.setRowFilter(null);
    } else {
        sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text3));
    }
}
```

One table is sorted, the other gives an error

```
 private void jTFSearchOtherKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                          
        jTableOther.setRowSorter(sorter);
        String text3 = jTFSearchOther.getText();
        if (text3.length() == 0) {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text3));
        }
    }  

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at testovoezadanie.demo.SQLiteTableModel.getValueAt(SQLiteTableModel.java:137)
    at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2719)
    at javax.swing.JTable.prepareRenderer(JTable.java:5720)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2114)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:777)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1053)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:886)
```

On line 137

```
@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        return contents[row][column];
    }
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B607dCDM9vn3aTNIRi1vYXRjcm8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry but not enough information to help with the problem. Consider posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also don't use KeyListener. Use DocumentListener instead.

Comment: Your exception is caused by a bug in SQLiteTableModel. That's the code you should post.

Comment: Please download the application, it is not a virus

Comment: Please make your question clear, by posting the relevant code. We won't download anything. And your question won't make sense anymore when you remove the file from your drive.

Comment: How do I attach files to this post so you can see them?

Comment: You don't. You post the relevant code in your question, properly formatted and indented as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contents Array may have other reference then that asked by the model when the filter applied ,
so try this

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {

        if(contents.length>row && contents[row].length>column)
        return contents[row][column];
        return null;//must solve this issue when object not found
    }
```

Comment: wrong answer (accepted answer can't be deleted) not is about add DocumentListener to JTextField, for more info to read Official Oracle tutorial How to use Tables, part Sorting and Filtering, especially for working code example in SSCCE/MCVE form

Comment: what is wrong in checking the if array index exist before accessing it and for the first i haven't answered i said "may" and this to avoid that index out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

Here filtration takes place

```
    private void updateTableManager() throws SQLException {

    SQLiteTableModel modelManager;

    modelManager = new SQLiteTableModel(connectDB, "VIEW_MANAGER");

    jTableManager.setModel(modelManager);

    sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modelManager);

    sorter.setComparator(2, new SQLiteComparator());

    jTableManager.setRowSorter(sorter);
}
```

Here is no

```
    private void updateTableWorker() throws SQLException {

    SQLiteTableModel modelWorker;

    modelWorker = new SQLiteTableModel(connectDB, "VIEW_MANAGER_WORKER");

    jTableManagerWorker.setModel(modelWorker);

    sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modelWorker);

    sorter.setComparator(2, new SQLiteComparator());

    jTableManagerWorker.setRowSorter(sorter);
}
```